# have no idea with nullptr, why i shouldn't use nullptr when i init my queue list

Tags: c, data-structures

i trying to make kiosk program for my school work.  it does not make any wrong signal when i compile it. but when i try to init my queue list it said that i can not use nullptr... i can not understand what's wrong with my code.

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct Node* link;
}Node;

typedef struct
{
    Node* front;
    Node* rear;
}QueueTypeNode;

QueueTypeNode* init_node(QueueTypeNode* head)
{
    head->front= NULL;
    head->front->link = head->rear;
    head->rear = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

Comment: OT: The code you show does not define `struct Node`. So as it stands it won't compile.

Comment: If you're using `nullptr`, you are using a C++ construct — and it is not unreasonable for a C compiler to reject it.  Your code doesn't show any use of `nullptr`; it uses `NULL`, which is fine in C (and in C++, but it is kinda old-fashioned).

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
head->front= NULL;
head->front->link = head->rear;
```

You assign `head->front` to NULL and then immediately dereference the NULL pointer by accessing `head->front->link`. This you cannot do as it results in undefined behavior and probably is giving you the runtime error you are observing.

Comment: if i want to make a connected list type then what should i fix?